# Getting an ID from 3 tables which has duplicate(multiple) keys and unique(single) key according to condition

Tags: mysql

I've tables like

**places**

```
uid place     country
1   Kolkata   23
2   Walhaba   47
2   New York  4
3   Ariadaha  23
3   Mandirpur 23
3   Vala      23
```

**perinfo**

```
uid relation name   hfor
1   1        ario   5
2   5        tina54 2
3   2        kiako2 2
```

**likes**

```
uid likeid
1   4
2   12
2   34
2   56
3   101
1   2
1   56
2   56
```

here u can see **perinfo** has uid as uniqueid but **likes** & **places** has a set of **uid**s

now i want to search for the **uid** who likes 34, lives in Walhaba and with hfor 2
(which is uid 2 int his example and could be many)

i've tried inner join but its showing duplicate(all) results for **places** and **likes**.
i just want single results for each match.
how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.uid
FROM    perinfo p
        INNER JOIN likes l
            ON p.uid = l.uid
        INNER JOIN places pl
            ON p.uid = pl.uid
WHERE   p.hfor = 2
GROUP   BY p.uid
HAVING  SUM(pl.place = 'walhaba') >= 1   -- <== must have a match
        AND SUM(l.likeID = 34) >= 1      -- <== must have a match
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dcdf0/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **DISTINCT** keyword to remove *duplicated* uid's:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.uid
FROM perinfo p 
    LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.uid = p.uid
    LEFT JOIN places pl ON pl.uid = p.uid
WHERE l.likeid = 34
    AND pl.place = 'Walhaba'
    AND p.hfor = 2
```

#### Update

The following is the equivalent SQL using the **GROUP BY** clause:

```
SELECT p.uid
FROM perinfo p 
    LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.uid = p.uid
    LEFT JOIN places pl ON pl.uid = p.uid
WHERE l.likeid = 34
    AND pl.place = 'Walhaba'
    AND p.hfor = 2
GROUP BY p.uid
```

Comment: @Hanze `DISTINCT` is a special case of using `GROUP BY` (see the updated answer and the [official document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html). Applying aggregate function requires extra work thus induces slight overhead to the execution time.